# android app launched status

Tags: android, launch

We are launching other applications from our android app. We are calling the app using the following code.

```
final PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
Intent LaunchIntent = pm
        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(PACKAGE_NAME);
mContext.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

My question is how can we get the status of the launched app, whether it is crashed or not.